# Live Data Visualization using R and mongoDB

Tags: r, node.js, mongodb, data-visualization, shinyjs

My aim is to create a visual data representation of Temperature data coming from a street light via sensors. I am picking that data from the mongoDB database. Basically in my knowledge and experience, I used Shiny And R to show static data graphs from the database, but I am unable to find any way of showing continuously updating data in a moving line chart. I hope you get the picture.

Please refer to this example using node.js(I want to achieve results similar to this but using R)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nauRfoNNEQs

My questions is, is there a way to show real time data visualization in R or I have to necessarily use node.js with plotly?

Comment: Seems more like a "Do my project for me" question. Voting to close as "too broad".

Comment: Not really, I just want to know if there is any such library available for R. I have searched multiple pages but I believe R does not support real time data streaming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how "live" you can get the stream, but you might want to look into this:

https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/reactivePoll.html

http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/reactive-poll-and-file-reader.html